Number sentences in paragraphs, as a range
I need to typeset a critical edition of a small philosophical work.
Editorial and typesetting rules require to number sentences at the beginning of each paragraph.
That is easy for 1-sentence paragraphs.  But for multi-sentence paragraphs I need to print the range.
How to incrementally number sentences in paragraphs as a range, like the sequential numbers in square brackets shown below?
Example

Talk on the Practical Reality
[1] Reality is at once a simple and a complicated word.
[2-3] For an ordinary, unaspiring human being, reality is a far cry. At every moment life offers him frustration.
[4-6] His life is the life of desire. When his desires are not fulfilled, he is frustrated. And when his desires are fulfilled, still he feels no abiding satisfaction; therefore, according to him everything is unreal.
(etc.)

MWE
I have a MWE, which only number paragraphs:
\documentclass{book}

\newcounter{para}
\newcommand\mypara{\par[\refstepcounter{para}\thepara] \space}

\begin{document}

\mypara (This should be [1]) Reality is at once a simple and a complicated word.

\mypara (This should be [2-3]) For an ordinary, unaspiring human being, reality is a far cry.  At every moment life offers him frustration.

\mypara (this should be [4-6]. His life is the life of desire.  When his desires are not fulfilled, he is frustrated. And when his desires are fulfilled, still he feels no abiding satisfaction; therefore, according to him everything is unreal.

\end{document}

Answers and packages (but insufficient)
I am aware of these answers:

Numbering the sentences in a text

Is it possible to automatically enumerate sentences in LaTeX?

Also, package scrjura


But they do not seem to help my need, to number the range of sentences in paragraphs.

This answer may help, but with a quite complex macro:

How to count the number of words in a sentence, the number of sentences in a paragraph, and the number of paragraph?
Question
Is there a package, or a simpler macro, to help incrementally number sentences in paragraphs, as a range?
Thanks in advance.

Can't you count the sentences using one of those solutions and just use the count at the start and end of each paragraph? If you want the range in the margin, you may find it occasionally ends up on the wrong page. If you put it in the text, you shouldn't have that problem.

Thanks for the idea, but no, I need to follow given editorial and typesetting rules. Sentence numbers, including ranges, need to be at the beginning of each paragraph, like shown above.

I am sorry, I am not that fluent with LaTeX, I was unable to understand the suggestion and its implications. Would you consider writing an answer to a non-specialist like myself, perhaps with some code?

It was only an idea ;). If nobody else answers, I'll see what I can do, but I'm hoping somebody else answers. That is, somebody who knows what they're doing ....

Thank you. Any help would be much appreciated.

I should say that I thought you wanted the sentences counted automatically. It is quite doable if you are prepared to mark the sentences. It's easy to handle the paragraphs automatically using the hooks the kernel now provides. And you can do it in any engine. (Which may not matter if you use LuaTeX anyhow.)

Here's a re-implementation of yannisl's answer which does not depend on Lua (so should work with any engine), avoids the need to start and end the environment for each paragraph and eliminates the need to explicitly capture the content of the paragraphs using the b specifier. Instead, the code is automatically added to the start and end of paragraphs.
Which is all well and good, but it is not for free. Everything has its price. In this case, the price is dependence on multiple compilations. You need at least two and sometimes three compilations for the numbering to be correct. This is because the numbers are written at the start of the paragraph, when only the first sentence's number is known for this run. To get the number of the last sentence, we record its value at the end of the paragraph and read it back on the next run. So, initially, the final sentences of all paragraphs will be zero and you will see things like '9-0' in the output. That is expected.
An alternative would be to capture the paragraph, but there are some downsides to doing that, so I decided not to complicate things.
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/719068/ addaswyd o ateb yannisl: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/719024/

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \g_gsl_sentences_int
\int_new:N \g_gsl_pars_int
\property_new:nnnn { sinpar }{ now }{ 0 }{ \int_use:N \g_gsl_sentences_int }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \sn #1 \n {
  \int_gincr:N \g_gsl_sentences_int
  #1 ~
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{segmentation} {}
{
  \hook_gput_code:nnn { para/begin } { gsl }
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g_gsl_pars_int
    \hbox_gset:Nn \g_para_indent_box { [\int_to_arabic:n {\g_gsl_sentences_int} -- \property_ref:ee { gsl@para@\int_to_arabic:n {\g_gsl_pars_int} } {sinpar} ] ~ }
  }
  \hook_gput_code:nnn { para/end } { gsl }
  {
    \property_record:ee { gsl@para@\int_to_arabic:n {\g_gsl_pars_int} } { sinpar } 
  }
}{
  \para_end:
  \hook_gremove_code:nn { para / begin } { gsl }
  \hook_gremove_code:nn { para / end } { gsl }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\begin{segmentation}
  \sn Myfirst sentence.\n
  \sn My second sentence.\n
  \sn My third sentence.\n 

  \sn My fourth sentence.\n 
  \sn My fifth sentence.\n
  \sn His life is the life of desire.\n 
  \sn My fifth sentence.\n
  \sn His life is the life of desire.\n 

  \sn This is the next in line!\n
  \sn This is the next in line!\n
\end{segmentation}

Here's some regular text in sentences which aren't marked and in paragraphs which don't get the special treatment.

And here's another.
These sentences aren't marked or counted either.
That's because we finished the \texttt{segmentation} environment and haven't started another.

\begin{segmentation}
  \sn Here we go again.\n
  \sn Counting sentences one-by-one.\n
  
  \sn However, we don't have to add the environment explicitly.\n
  \sn So it is a bit more automatic.\n
\end{segmentation}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}


Note: the truth is, this was going to depend on Lua because I planned to just add the hooks wrapper around yannisl's code. But I know nothing about Lua and couldn't even figure out how to do that.
EDIT
This version offers ranges and/or sentence numbers on a per-environment or general basis and provides a key-value interface for customising the appearance of both.
\glsset{<list of key-values>} or an optional argument to the segmentation environment may be used for the customisation. All settings are local.

sentence numbers=<true|false> determines whether numbers are printed.

Default is true; initially false.


sentence ranges=<true|false> determines whether ranges are printed.

Default is true; initially true.


sentence number format={<code taking one argument>} determines the format of sentence numbers, where #1 is the sentence number.
sentence range format={<code taking two arguments>} determines the format of ranges, where #1 is the first sentence in the paragraph and #2 is the second.

Note that this will obviously be slightly slower than the less flexible code above.
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/719068/ addaswyd o ateb yannisl: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/719024/
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \g_gsl_sentences_int
\int_new:N \g_gsl_pars_int
\property_new:nnnn { sinpar }{ now }{ 0 }{ \int_use:N \g_gsl_sentences_int }

\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \gsl_sentence_no_format:n
{
  \textsubscript{ \textcolor{gray}{ #1 } }
}
\cs_set_protected_nopar:Nn \gsl_sentence_range_format:nn
{
  [ #1 -- #2 ]
}

\keys_define:nn { gsl }
{
  sentence ~ number ~ format .code:n = {
    \cs_set_protected_nopar:Nn \gsl_sentence_no_format:n { #1 }
  },
  sentence ~ numbers .bool_set:N = \g_gsl_sentence_nos_bool,
  sentence ~ numbers .initial:n = false,
  sentence ~ numbers .default:n = true,
  sentence ~ range ~ format .code:n = {
    \cs_set_protected_nopar:Nn \gsl_sentence_range_format:nn { #1 }
  },
  sentence ~ ranges .bool_set:N = \g_gsl_sentence_ranges_bool,
  sentence ~ ranges .initial:n = true,
  sentence ~ ranges .default:n = true,
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \sn #1 \n {
  \int_gincr:N \g_gsl_sentences_int
  #1 \bool_if:NT \g_gsl_sentence_nos_bool 
  {
    \gsl_sentence_no_format:n { \int_to_arabic:n {\g_gsl_sentences_int} } 
  } ~
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{segmentation} { o }
{
  \IfValueT { #1 } 
  {
    \keys_set:nn { gsl } { #1 }
  }
  \bool_if:NT \g_gsl_sentence_ranges_bool
  {
    \hook_gput_code:nnn { para/begin } { gsl }
    {
      \int_gincr:N \g_gsl_pars_int
%       \hbox_gset:Nn \g_para_indent_box { [\int_to_arabic:n {\g_gsl_sentences_int} -- \property_ref:ee { gsl@para@\int_to_arabic:n {\g_gsl_pars_int} } {sinpar} ] ~ }
      \hbox_gset:Nn \g_para_indent_box { \gsl_sentence_range_format:nn { \int_to_arabic:n {\g_gsl_sentences_int} } { \property_ref:ee { gsl@para@\int_to_arabic:n {\g_gsl_pars_int} } {sinpar} } ~ }
    }
    \hook_gput_code:nnn { para/end } { gsl }
    {
      \property_record:ee { gsl@para@\int_to_arabic:n {\g_gsl_pars_int} } { sinpar } 
    }
  }
}{
  \para_end:
  \bool_if:NT \g_gsl_sentence_ranges_bool
  {
    \hook_gremove_code:nn { para / begin } { gsl }
    \hook_gremove_code:nn { para / end } { gsl }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \gslset { m }
{
  \keys_set:nn { gsl } { #1 }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{segmentation}
  \sn My first sentence.\n
  \sn My second sentence.\n
  \sn My third sentence.\n 

  \sn My fourth sentence.\n 
  \sn My fifth sentence.\n
  \sn His life is the life of desire.\n 
  \sn My fifth sentence.\n
  \sn His life is the life of desire.\n 

  \sn This is the next in line!\n
  \sn This is the next in line!\n
\end{segmentation}

Here's some regular text in sentences which aren't marked and in paragraphs which don't get the special treatment.

And here's another.
These sentences aren't marked or counted either.
That's because we finished the \texttt{segmentation} environment and haven't started another.

\begin{segmentation}
  \sn Here we go again.\n
  \sn Counting sentences one-by-one.\n
  
  \sn However, we don't have to add the environment explicitly.\n
  \sn So it is a bit more automatic.\n
\end{segmentation}

\begin{segmentation}[sentence ranges=false]
  \sn My first sentence.\n
  \sn My second sentence.\n
  \sn My third sentence.\n 

  \sn My fourth sentence.\n 
  \sn My fifth sentence.\n
  \sn His life is the life of desire.\n 
  \sn My fifth sentence.\n
  \sn His life is the life of desire.\n 

  \sn This is the next in line!\n
  \sn This is the next in line!\n
\end{segmentation}

Here's some regular text in sentences which aren't marked and in paragraphs which don't get the special treatment.

And here's another.
These sentences aren't marked or counted either.
That's because we finished the \texttt{segmentation} environment and haven't started another.

\begin{segmentation}[sentence numbers]
  \sn Here we go again.\n
  \sn Counting sentences one-by-one.\n
  
  \sn However, we don't have to add the environment explicitly.\n
  \sn So it is a bit more automatic.\n
\end{segmentation}

\gslset{%
  sentence ranges=true,
  sentence numbers=true,
  sentence range format={\textit{\textcolor{blue}{\small (#1--#2)}}},
  sentence number format={\textsuperscript{\textcolor{red}{#1}}},
}%

\begin{segmentation}
  \sn My first sentence.\n
  \sn My second sentence.\n
  \sn My third sentence.\n 

  \sn My fourth sentence.\n 
  \sn My fifth sentence.\n
  \sn His life is the life of desire.\n 
  \sn My fifth sentence.\n
  \sn His life is the life of desire.\n 

  \sn This is the next in line!\n
  \sn This is the next in line!\n
\end{segmentation}

Here's some regular text in sentences which aren't marked and in paragraphs which don't get the special treatment.

And here's another.
These sentences aren't marked or counted either.
That's because we finished the \texttt{segmentation} environment and haven't started another.

\begin{segmentation}
  \sn Here we go again.\n
  \sn Counting sentences one-by-one.\n
  
  \sn However, we don't have to add the environment explicitly.\n
  \sn So it is a bit more automatic.\n
\end{segmentation}
\end{document}

The blue and red is hideous, but illustrates the idea.


Thank you very much. I do not mind at all compiling several times, since I need to do that in any case (for indexes, etc). I wish I could choose both solutions as accepted answer, as they are both working and useful. tex.sx may not be too good in this regards, in not allowing one to do so. I am choosing this answer, as more general, and thus serving typesetters not using LuaTeX. Thank you also for your kind suggestions, they helped me better refine the question.

I think since you using hooks, maybe try also with \obeylines this might avoid the \sn, \n marking and would be the simplest API.

@yannisl You mean capture the end of line? We don't actually want the line breaks in the output. But .... I can think of one way to do it, but I think it would be slow.

@gsl Do you usually input one sentence per line in your source? I do, but not everyone does.

@cfr It depends on the source. Some authors wish to give a sentence more weight, by making it a self-standing paragraph. It comes to mind some Biblical studies, or Buddhist canons, or some philosophers. I would say, most of my work has multi-sentence paragraphs, about 30% are single sentence.

@gls  Most segmenters (if you automate) will output the sentences as paragraphs see  https://www.crimsoni.ai/katana/#  The definition of a sentence though is highly depended on the language and the script. If that Buddhist canon is in Tibetan is a totally different ball game. Even in English sometimes a stop does not denote an end of a sentence, it can be an abbreviation!

@gsl I meant do you put each sentence on its own line in your .tex file. That has nothing to do with the output. Almost all my paragraphs have multiple sentences, but almost all my .tex files have new lines following each sentence. (To the point that I have to do find & replace to join them if I'm writing for a word processor because I tend to automatically break the lines when inputting. Though not on the web as much. Go figure.)

@yannisl Won't \obeylines undermine the automatic detection of paragraphs. If I make the new line active, don't I end up with no blank lines for the paragraphs?

@cfr  \obeylines  will turn everything into paragraphs. In this case you will need to check for an empty capture, i.e., the blank lines and discard them. But you can avoid the \sn and \n. Just each sentence on one line.

@yannisl But then every sentence will be its own paragraph, which isn't the target output, as I understand it. I think what I'd have to do would be to make the new line active but set it to something else. Then capture two subsequent new lines and turn that into a paragraph ending.

Unless @gsl wants each sentence in its own paragraph? In that case the ranges thing becomes a non-issue because every paragraph will have only one sentence.

@cfr  The environment collects the paragraph (that is why I used the +b, as this was my first attempt). I think is more natural for what the OP is using it it for. Very similar to the code I had for epigraphy some time back, that you got involved. In that case we numbered the lines. In the OP case he only  needs the range. Thinking aloud that might be modified to do this.

As said in other comment, most of my work (and I believe most people working in humanities) have multi-sentence paragraphs.

@gsl I'm a philosopher ;). But I emphasise again: I'm not talking about what appears in your document. I'm talking about what's in your .tex file. Look, do you use backslashes often in your work? Probably not in the output, but I bet you've a fair number in your input, right? This is just the same. It's nothing to do with your discipline. That's a matter of output. It's a matter of coding style, if you like. How you like to have your input formatted - what kind of indentation you use, whether you use rows of percentage signs to delineate sections etc. How do you use newlines there?

@gsl I write hundreds of pages without using a single backslash. That's true. (Almost) all my sentences have multiple sentences. Equally true. But that's only half the story. I use backslashes frequently in my writing. True. Every document includes at least 3, after all. I put each sentence on its own line. Equally true. Just as I tend to put % BEGIN sec:<label> and % END sec:<label> at the start and end of each section. That's just for code-folding. Similarly, a newline per sentence is really for version control. That's just how I use TeX regardless of what I'm writing.

@gsl I'm asking because yannisl's suggestion is to use line breaks to delimit the sentences. If you put each sentence on its own line, that will make life easier (potentially). But, if you don't, it might be more of a pain than \n.

@cfr Truly honoured to meet a philosopher! For my typesetting works, the "source of truth" is the original markdown text files.  Those are under version control, too. They are converted to LaTex with Pandoc, and a series of "filters" applied (mainly Perl regex substitutions). My LaTex work concerns the «framework» (format, etc). I try hard to never change content in LaTex. I would not want to have to worry about changes in both source and LaTex code.

@gsl ;) So then the question is whether it would be any easier to have new lines as delimiters rather than \sn ... \n. If your .tex files aren't the source, I'm guessing it makes less difference.

I believe this "sentence range" use-case is quite common. I hope this code will become a small package at some point. In such case, the more flexibility the  better. I liked for example @yannisl option to also have sentence number as small digit at the end fo the sentence. I can see I could use that sometimes, perhaps having the range in red, and the sentence-number in gray. But the functionality here is already excellent.

@gsl Is there a style guide for this type of annotation somewhere on the web? And yes I can turn this into a small package.

Thank you @yannisl ! I need to follow the editorial guide of the publisher I work for. It is not online, one could look at an abridged version here: https://www.libraweb.net/Norme.pdf (btw, that is not the publisher I work for)
It is based on both French and Italian typographical tradition, with a bit of British rules from before 20th century. A main source for information would be the Italian volume «Regole editoriali, tipografiche e redazionali.» by F Serra. The volume contains two nice contributions by A. Olschki and M. Mardersteig

@gsl See edit for a version which can number the sentences (or not) and lets you customise the formats used for numbers/ranges. If I figure out the line ending thing, I'll update.

@cfr This works perfectly!

Run this with LuaLaTeX. Sentence segmentation is a major topic in Natural Language Processing, so you will have to mark the beginning of a sentence with \sn and the end with  stop . If a sentence ends say with a ; or ! you will still need to add the stop afterwards as it uses a delimited macro. This shouldn't be too cumbersome, and if you generating these through a machine learning program, you can arrange for this to be added automatically. Paragraphs are marked with the environment segmentation.
Tips! You can change the macro delimiter from . to another symbol depending on your use case. David Carlisle or another user might be able to change the macro to capture an eol character automatically thus automating the delimiter. (I dont' remember how to do it).
The code will fail for RTL scripts such as Hebrew, Arabic for other scripts, including east Asian scripts, such as Japanese or Chinese as long as you mark the sentences, it shouldn't give you any issues and the reason why I used Lua, as is more versatile when it comes to using non-Latin scripts.
You can change the tex.print(str3)  to (str1) or (str2) for differnt styles of marking the sentences.


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
  M=M or {}
  M.data ={}
  M.last =1
  M.initial=1
  M.insertdata=function(x)
    table.insert(M.data,x)
    M.last=M.last + 1
    end
   M.clear=function()
     for k=1,#M.data do
     table.remove(M.data,1)
     end
   end   
\end{luacode}

\long\def\sn#1\n{%
\directlua{
 M.insertdata('#1')
}}

\long\def\printparagraph{{%
\parindent=0pt
%tex.print("\\itshape "..v,"["..(k+initial-1).."]".." ")
\directlua{
  local data = M.data
  local initial = M.initial
  local current_length= table.getn(data)+initial
  tex.print("[".. initial.. "-"..(current_length-1).."]")
  for k,v in pairs(data) do
  local str  = "\\itshape "..v.." "
  local str1 = "\\itshape "..v,"["..(k+initial-1).."]".." "
  local str2 =  "\\itshape "..v,"["..(k+initial-1).."]".." "
  local str3  = "\\itshape "..v.."\\textsubscript{"..(k+initial-1).."}"
  tex.print(str3)
  M.initial=current_length
end   
}}\par}

 
\def\mypara{
 ------------------------------\par
\directlua{
  M.clear()
}}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{segmentation}{+b}
{\mypara #1\printparagraph}
{}
\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\begin{segmentation}
\sn Myfirst sentence.\n
\sn My second sentence.\n
\sn My third sentence.\n 
\end{segmentation}
\begin{segmentation}
\sn My fourth sentence.\n 
\sn My fifth sentence.\n
\sn His life is the life of desire.\n 
\sn My fifth sentence.\n
\sn His life is the life of desire.\n 
\end{segmentation}
\begin{segmentation}
\sn This is the next in line!\n
\sn This is the next in line!\n
\end{segmentation}
\end{document}


Thank you, this is working almost fine. Is there a way to: 1. make it precise; now the range at first paragraph says "[1-4]:, while it should be "[1-3]". Same for other paragraphs, they are off by +1?  2. Remove the sentence numbers inside the paragraphs (like in my example, they only appear at the left). 3. Is there a way to hide the dot, like at "! ."where necessary, perhaps making it invisible?

Please see edit. As mentioned in the edit just use str1, or str2, or str3 for different styles of sentence markings str is what you asked. Also note delimited macro markup changes, marked with \n . Can be anything actually , do a bit of reading on delimited macros.

This is very impressive, but \def\veryshortnamewhichisverylikelytoconflictwithsomethingimportant is not good practice. You can always say \newcommand\sn{} before so you get an error if there's a problem. Or you can use expl3, obviously. (And, yes, I know it is perfectly OK here, but it might be less OK with the addition of some packages and it is not good as an example of how to do things.)

@cfr  obviously, just kept it simple for the OP.  Code also needs to be in a lua module and .sty file. Left as an exercise for the OP :)  As expl3  yes, if you need to add a key value interface  etc and some lovely quarks :)

@cfr also another improvement is to keep the API simple but define the delimted macro within the environment so to ensure that there is little chance of conflict. The \n  gets absorbed in any case.

Thank you deeply for this macro, it does exactly what I need. I am also learning a lot from your Lua code. Please, would you consider making this a small package? I am sure it would be useful to many who typeset works in humanities.

@cfr sorry if my response came as if I am disparaging expl3 code. I use it a lot myself, and  Iam glad you posted an alternative exp3 solution. This was the spirit of this site in its early years, where posts provided many alternative solutions, each with its own advantages and disadvantages.  My first attempt was actually using an expl3 hybrid. Captured the sentences through a delimited macro (as the user needs to mark them ) then put them in a clist, so I can iterate and put the counters etc. Then I opted for Lua, as I wanted to try it with various non-latin scripts.

@yannisl It's OK. Give me another 2 minutes and I would have deleted that comment. I already almost deleted it twice. And I know you use expl3. If I understood Lua, I wouldn't have re-implemented yours anyway - all I meant to do was add it into the paragraph hooks. But I couldn't make it work. Either I got errors or the document compiled but produced no actual output. Not terribly surprising. I don't understand Lua at all.

@yannisl I will thoroughly test both answers in my current work. In case, I will re-evaluate. It seems to me, beside the single compilation, your answer is a bit faster. Sometimes my work includes several hundred pages, and speed is quite often an important aspect. Thank you again for your work. I am learning a lot. As they say, I owe you one.
